# Why do my POSTGRES composite key can't accept this input?

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase

I'm creating a table with contents in a Postgres (Supabase) server. This table should have solely the content id.

In another table, I'm storing the translations for this content (i.e. the content id, the language and country codes of the translation and the translated text).

Something like this:
contents_table
language_codes_table
country_codes_table
contents_translation

In the contents table, I'm trying to use as a primary key  a combination from 3 foreign keys, which are the Language Code, the Country Code and the Content id.

I'm creating the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.contents_localization_test (
  content_id uuid REFERENCES public.contents (content_id),
  lang_code text REFERENCES public.lang_codes (lang_code),
  country_code text REFERENCES public.lang_country_codes (country_code),
  content_name text,
  CONSTRAINT unique_entry PRIMARY KEY (content_id, lang_code, country_code)
);
```

Entries I was expecting to be accepted:

(
"my-id-1",
"en",
"US",
"Text in English"
)

(
"my-id-1",
"pt",
"BR",
"Texto em Português"
)

They are not accepted explicitly because of the id duplication. What am i doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**
Sample of data that is accepted (it's the first one):

```
content_id : 68f8ebc2-ac50-44d0-a626-4babd343d2f9
lang_code: pt
country_code: BR
content_name: Tabela Periódica
```

Sample of data that isn't accepted:

```
content_id : 68f8ebc2-ac50-44d0-a626-4babd343d2f9
lang_code: en
country_code: US
content_name: Periodic Table
```

This is the error:
Error: Error: insert or update on table "contents_localization_test" violates foreign key constraint "contents_localization_test_country_code_fkey

---

EDIT 2

After removing the reference to the countries_table, the problem is gone.

---

EDIT 3
I found the problem. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Why it should trigger a duplication? I'm sorry but I'm quite a newbie in Postgres. Since it is a composite key, it isn't supposed to be "evaluated" as a whole instead as each "piece" of key?

Comment: This is the error: Error: Error: insert or update on table "contents_localization" violates foreign key constraint

Comment: Yeah, if you have repeated instances of say `("my-id-1", "en", "US")` then you would get a duplicate error.  Though I'm not sure how that is happening if `content_id` is really a `uuid`?

Comment: Yes, it is just an example sorry, I thought it was better to simplify :P. The original id is  68f8ebc2-ac50-44d0-a626-4babd343d2f9
I'm not repeating instances of the same id and language code, unfortunately.
I don't know if this is a bug, or I'm doing something wrong, or even if is something specifically from Supabase (which I doubt since I created the table using pure sql)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I was intending to throw those duplication errors only  when a repeated entry was being given for a language and id, so it would not allow to have many translations for the same language for the same piece of text. But since I'm using two different language codes I can't spot the problem

Comment: I was not fully paying attention in my first comment, see the follow up. Is the `contents_localization` table the same as `contents_localization_test`, because I don't see it in your example.

Comment: You really need to provide a ***complete*** example; one that has enough example data, etc, to reliably reproduce your error.  Because, based on what you've given, there is no error... See here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=58d84a2eb2b7474fe8caa9238fa937ab

Comment: I'm going to say one or more of  the FKs in `contents_localization(_test)` do not have a value in the table(s) they are referencing. That is what the error is saying, not that there is an issue with the PK.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes, they're both the same. I created a new table to start from zero (then the _test) but they have the same content and throw the same error when doing this operation.

Comment: I'll add more details @MatBailie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I solved it:

---

EDIT

Thank you Adrian!

I decided to deactivate/activate each one of the <s>primary</s> **foreign** keys (i.e. remove <s>them from the primary key</s> **their reference as a foreign key**) and see what happens. I started with the country_code table. I deactivated it, tried to add repeated country with differente language codes (ok! it passed!). Then I tried to add a new entry with the same country code, the same language code and the same content_id. The error clearly stated that this new insert wasn't possible because the id was duplicate (which now was!).
So I suppose  my contry_codes table got corrupted somehow (I can't guess when or how this happened though).

**My country tables was broken** (I don't have any idea why!) and was breaking everything else. The table itself was fine, but it looks like it had a circular reference (I don't know how to name it) that made the country code count as itself two times (I'm doing guessing here...). In short: I needed to create a new country_codes table with every single code of the first and change references for this second. Everything now works.

I was using their UI to create this table, so maybe a bug ocurried while doing this or refreshing the browser.

Just to be clear: this second version of the table HAS THE SAME PROPERTIES OF THE FIRST, the same foreign keys and the same colums' names. So I suppose a kind of bug or crazy thing that I can't understand happened when I created the first table.

So if you are seeing this from the future: please deactivate and activate each of the composite keys, then try adding content that should be permitted and that shouldn't to compare. This way you can find the problematic table. I hope it's only one lol.

**Thank you all for you help and for understanding my awful english :D!**

Comment: You where not deactivating the primary key so much as deactivating the foreign key reference. To repeat the PK was not at fault here, it was the FK references. Is just so happened the PK included all the FK references. You would have got the same error if `country_code` had not been part of the PK.

Comment: YES! I will edit my own answer :o
Thank you so much Adrian! You're absolutely right. I typed it wrong but meant the same.